# Getting new allocated memory size in python

Tags: python-3.x, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I'm looking for a way to get memory size of new allocated python objects to monitor memory usages of code blocks. For example, for time monitoring we usually use code like

```py
t = time.time()
# ... long operation
t_used = time.time() - t
```

Is there a way to make something same with memory (in Python3)? To get size of allocated memory of new objects (doesn't matter memory free operations). I've found a good solution as [guppy](https://coderzcolumn.com/tutorials/python/guppy-heapy-profile-memory-usage-in-python), but it has no support for Python3

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html

Answer (score 0):

Having studied different ways to solve it I decided that the most light and easy way to perform same task is using `gc` with `psutil`:

```py
def _get_value():
    import gc, os, psutil
    gc.collect()
    return psutil.Process(os.getpid()).memory_info().rss / 1024 ** 2

t = _get_value()
# ... operation
t_used = _get_value() - t
```

It works not so clean but very fast and doesn't need big memory allocation or some new dependencies